# java gradle Cannot find github repository to compile

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github, gradle

Hi Im having issues with gradle settings in my Java Android app in android studio.

Im trying to compile a github repository https://github.com/MatthewLM/peercoinj

My Code:

> compile 'com.github.matthewlm:peercoinj:0.13.1'

This is the output:

> Could not find com.github.matthewlm:peercoinj:0.13.1.

I hope you can help me

Comment: i think you can't build it with gradle you have to use maven and it is not for android

Comment: Which repositories did you register?

Answer (score 0):

The version might have changed.  You might try changing that line to:

```
compile 'com.github.matthewlm:peercoinj:+'
```

Be aware though that this method is not preferred as it can lead to unstable builds (eg. third party could release a newer version of their code which might break something in your code).  Hope it helps.  Good luck OP.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment.
Now But I have a different error, but I think it found it but wont work because of this error:
Unsupported ContentType text/plain; charset=utf-8 for directory listing 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/matthewlm/peercoinj/'

Comment: This is not useful, simply because it is totally unclear in which repository the dependency should be. If the repositoriy would be known, one could simply check if the specified version exists instead of relying on a wildcard version.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the artifact is not uploaded to maven repository.
So you need to install maven locally, clone the project from github.
Than run mvn clean install. This will install the artifact in your local maven repo
Only than you can use the artifact in your own project.

Comment: Sorry, im new to all of this. How do i do this?